# Fermat Near Misses

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence

Fermat's last theorem says that there there are no positive, integral solutions to the equation `a^n + b^n = c^n` for any `n>2`. This was proven to be true by Andrew Wiles in 1994.

However, there are many "near misses" that almost satisfy the diophantine equation but miss it by one. Precisely, they are all the greater than 1 and are integral solutions of `a^3 + b^3 = c^3 + 1` (the sequence is the value of each side of the equation, in increasing order).

#### Your task is given `n`, to print out the first `n` values of this sequence.

Here are the first few values of the sequence:

```
1729, 1092728, 3375001, 15438250, 121287376, 401947273, 3680797185, 6352182209, 7856862273, 12422690497, 73244501505, 145697644729, 179406144001, 648787169394, 938601300672, 985966166178, 1594232306569, 2898516861513, 9635042700640, 10119744747001, 31599452533376, 49108313528001, 50194406979073, 57507986235800, 58515008947768, 65753372717929, 71395901759126, 107741456072705, 194890060205353, 206173690790977, 251072400480057, 404682117722064, 498168062719418, 586607471154432, 588522607645609, 639746322022297, 729729243027001
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in **bytes** wins!

Comment: https://oeis.org/A050794

Comment: The first is Ramanujan's https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_number. Sequence of c, https://oeis.org/A050791 may be helpful.

Answer (score 14):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 16 bytes

```
*3‘
ḊŒc*3S€ċÇµ#Ç
```

Brute-force solution. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#AR8A4P//KjPigJgK4biKxZJjKjNT4oKsxIvDh8K1I8OH//8z)

```
*3‘           Helper link. Maps r to r³+1.

ḊŒc*3S€ċÇµ#Ç  Main link. No arguments.

         µ    Combine the links to the left into a chain.
          #   Read an integer n from STDIN and execute the chain to the left for
              k = 0, 1, 2, ... until n matches were found. Yield the matches.
Ḋ             Dequeue; yield [2, ..., k].
 Œc           Yield all 2-combinations of elements of that range.
   *3         Elevate the integers in each pair to the third power.
     S€       Compute the sum of each pair.
        Ç     Call the helper link, yielding k³+1.
       ċ      Count how many times k³+1 appears in the sums. This yields a truthy 
              (i.e., non-zero) integer if and only if k is a match.
           Ç  Map the helper link over the array of matches.
```

Answer (score 8):

## Perl, 78 bytes

```perl
#!perl -nl
grep$_<(($_+2)**(1/3)|0)**3,map$i**3-$_**3,2..$i++and$_-=print$i**3+1while$_
```

Brute force approach. Couting the shebang as two, input is taken from stdin.

**Sample Usage**

```perl
$ echo 10 | perl fermat-near-miss.pl
1729
1092728
3375001
15438250
121287376
401947273
3680797185
6352182209
7856862273
12422690497
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/perl#@59elFqgEm@joaESr22kqaWlYahvrFljAGQZ6@QmFqhkAhm6KvEgrpGenkqmtnZiXopKvK5tQVFmXglYWtuwPCMzJ1Ul/v9/Q4P/unk5AA)

Answer (score 8):

## [Brachylog](http://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 31 bytes

```
:{#T#>>:{:3^}aLhH,Lb+.-H,#T=,}y
```

[Try it online!](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=OnsjVCM-Pjp7OjNefWFMaEgsTGIrLi1ILCNUPSx9eQ&input=NQ&args=Wg&debug=on)

This is not complete brute force as this uses constraints. This is a bit slow on TIO (about 20 seconds for `N = 5`). Takes about 5 seconds for `N = 5` and 13 seconds for `N = 6` on my machine.

#### Explanation

```
:{                           }y    Return the first Input outputs of that predicate
  #T                               #T is a built-in list of 3 variables
    #>                             #T must contain strictly positive values
      >                            #T must be a strictly decreasing list of integers
       :{:3^}aL                    L is the list of cubes of the integers in #T
              LhH,                 H is the first element of L (the biggest)
                  Lb+.             Output is the sum of the last two elements of L
                     .-H,          Output - 1 = H
                         #T=,      Find values for #T that satisfy those constaints
```

Answer (score 7):

## Mathematica, 95 bytes

```
(b=9;While[Length[a=Select[Union@@Array[#^3+#2^3&,{b,b},2],IntegerQ[(#-1)^3^-1]&,#]]<#,b++];a)&
```

Unnamed function taking a single positive integer argument `#` and returning a list of the desired `#` integers. Spaced for human readability:

```
1  (b = 9; While[
2    Length[ a =
3      Select[
4        Union @@ Array[#^3 + #2^3 &, {b, b}, 2],
5        IntegerQ[(# - 1)^3^-1] &
6      , #]
7    ] < #, b++
8  ]; a) &
```

Line 4 calculates all possible sums of cubes of integers between 2 and `b`+1 (with the initialization `b=9` in line 1) in sorted order. Lines 3-5 select from those sums only those that are also one more than a perfect cube; line 6 limits that list to at most `#` values, which are stored in `a`. But if this list has in fact fewer than `#` values, the `While` loop in lines 1-7 increments `b` and tries again. Finally, line 8 outputs `a` once it's the right length.

Holy hell this version is slow! For one extra byte, we can change `b++` in line 7 to `b*=9` and make the code actually run in reasonable time (indeed, that's how I tested it).

Answer (score 6):

### Racket 166 bytes

```
(let((c 0)(g(λ(x)(* x x x))))(for*((i(in-naturals))(j(range 1 i))(k(range j i))#:final(= c n))
(when(=(+(g j)(g k))(+ 1(g i)))(displayln(+ 1(g i)))(set! c(+ 1 c)))))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(define (f n)
  (let ((c 0)
        (g (λ (x) (* x x x))))
    (for* ((i (in-naturals))
           (j (range 1 i))
           (k (range j i))
           #:final (= c n))
      (when (= (+ (g j) (g k))
               (+ 1 (g i)))
        (displayln (+ 1(g i)))
        (set! c (add1 c))))))
```

Testing:

```
(f 5)
```

Output:

```
1729
1092728
3375001
15438250
121287376
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>102</s> 98 bytes

```python
def f(n,c=2):z=c**3+1;t=z in[(k/c)**3+(k%c)**3for k in range(c*c)];return[z]*n and[z]*t+f(n-t,c+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#HY1BCoMwEEWvMhshk1hE21UlJ5EswpgUCUzLMG5y@TS6e/wH/7U9ZciGR/ILvqsna59uXtVXOHgzZSK8FlOGG/JXoHQDEvmTDFnCsErSU3irwTJE3i9Q1z8fOpKbsf3kYO2RF7Y/)

Answer (score 5):

## Pari/GP, 107 bytes

```
F(n)=c=2;while(n>0,c++;C=c^3+1;a=2;b=c-1;while(a<b,K=a^3+b^3;if(K==C,print(C);n--;break);if(K>C, b--,a++)))
```

Finds the first 10 solutions in 10 sec.

Goal:  ***a^3+b^3 = c^3+1***

1. Gets number of required solutions by function-argument ***n***
2. Increases ***c*** from ***3*** and for each ***c^3+1***
   searches ***a*** and ***b*** with ***1 < a <= b < c*** such that
   ***a^3+b^3=c^3+1*** . If found, decrease required number of further soulutions ***n*** by ***1***    and repeat
3. Finishes, when number of
   furtherly required solutions (in ***n***) equals ***0***

***Call it*** to get the first ten solutions:

```
F(10)
```

***Readable code*** (requires leading and trailing braces as indicators for block-notation of the function. Also for convenience prints all variables of a solution):

```
{F(m) = c=2;
   while(m>0,        
     c++;C=c^3+1;             
     a=2;b=c-1;                
     while(a<b,                
           K=a^3+b^3;               
            if(K==C,print([a,b,c,C]);m--;break);
            if(K>C, b--,a++);
          );
    );}
```

## Pari/GP, 93 bytes

(Improvement by Dennis)

```
F(n)=c=2;while(n,C=c^3+1;a=2;b=c++;while(a<b,if(K=a^3+b^3-C,b-=K>0;a+=K<0,print(C);n--;b=a)))
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! I took the liberty of giving you answer the usual format (some userscripts and Stack Snippets rely on that). [This](https://tio.run/nexus/pari-gp#LctBCoAgEEDR68ygguZSp43gxjsIoxQJIRFBxzcXbf/jjwgdqdLi3qOdG3QZqGYrjOPZClUhfmFfZNshEU8u2aogi6K0aseCktfyult/IKDrSs2TEXFEMBrHBw) seems to save a few bytes.

Comment: Hah, Dennis, thank you for the formatting. And the reduction is really cool! I've never seen that specific tweaks...  I'll take it into the answer as version.

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2, <s>122</s> 119 Bytes

<sup>*why are you still upvoting? Dennis crushed this answer ;)*</sup>

Welcome to the longest solution to this question :/ I managed to shave off a whole byte by making longer conditions and removing as much indentation as possible.

```python
x,y,z=2,3,4
n=input()
while n:
 if y**3+x**3-z**3==1and x<y<z:print z**3+1;n-=1
 x+=1
 if y<x:y+=1;x=2
 if z<y:z+=1;y=3
```

Output for `n = 5`:

```python
1729
1092728
3375001
15438250
121287376
```

Answer (score 4):

## TI-Basic, 90 bytes

There must be a shorter way...

```
Prompt N
2->X
3->Y
4->Z
While N
If 1=X³+Y³-Z³ and X<Y and Y<Z
Then
DS<(N,0
X+1->X
If Y<X
Then
2->X
Y+1->Y
End
If Z<Y
Then
3->Y
Z+1->Z
End
End
```

Answer (score 2):

### MATLAB, 94 bytes

Another brute-force solution:

```
for z=4:inf,for y=3:z,for x=2:y,c=z^3+1;if x^3+y^3==c,n=n-1;c,if~n,return,end,end,end,end,end
```

Output for `n=4`:

```
>> n=4; fermat_near_misses    
c =
        1729
c =
     1092728
c =
     3375001
c =
    15438250
```

Suppressing the `c=` part of the display increases the code to **100 bytes**

```
for z=4:inf,for y=3:z,for x=2:y,c=z^3+1;if x^3+y^3==c,n=n-1;disp(c),if~n,return,end,end,end,end,end

>> n=4; fermat_near_misses_cleandisp    
        1729
     1092728
     3375001
    15438250
```

Comment: Why are there 5 "end"s? Sorry I'm terrible at matlab

Comment: @ev3commander it's MATLAB's statement closing symbol, the "closing parenthesis" if you will

Answer (score 2):

## C#, <s>188</s> <s>174</s> <s>187</s> 136 bytes

Golfed version thanks to TheLethalCoder for his great code golfing and tips ([Try online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JkmJo3)):

```
n=>{for(long a,b,c=3;n>0;c++)for(a=2;a<c;a++)for(b=a;b<c;b++)if(a*a*a+b‌​*b*b==c*c*c+1)System‌​.Console.WriteLin‌e(‌​c*c*(a=c)+n/n--);};
```

Execution time to find the first 10 numbers: 33,370842 seconds on my i7 laptop (original version below was 9,618127 seconds for the same task).

**Ungolfed version:**

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Action<int> action = n =>
        {
            for (long a, b, d, c = 3; n > 0; c++)
                for (a = 2; a < c; a++)
                    for (b = a; b < c; b++)
                        if (a * a * a + b‌ * b * b == c * c * c + 1)
                            System‌.Console.WriteLin‌e( c * c * (a = c) + n / n--);
        };

        //Called like
        action(5);
    }
}
```

Previous golfed 187 bytes version including `using System;`

```
using System;static void Main(){for(long a,b,c=3,n=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());n>0;c++)for(a=2;a<c;a++)for(b=a;b<c;b++)if(a*a*a+b*b*b==c*c*c+1)Console.WriteLin‌​e(c*c*(a=c)+n/n--);}
```

Previous golfed 174 bytes version (thanks to Peter Taylor):

```
static void Main(){for(long a,b,c=3,n=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());n>0;c++)for(a=2;a<c;a++)for(b=a;b<c;b++)if(a*a*a+b*b*b==c*c*c+1)Console.WriteLin‌​e(c*c*(a=c)+n/n--);}
```

Previous (original) golfed 188 bytes version ([Try online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wzujnR)):

```
static void Main(){double a,b,c,d;int t=0,n=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());for(c=3;t<n;c++)for(a=2;a<c;a++)for(b=a;b<c;b++){d=(c*c*c)+1;if(a*a*a+b*b*b==d){Console.WriteLine(d);t++;}}}
```

Execution time to find the first 10 numbers: 9,618127 seconds on my i7 laptop.

This is my first ever attempt in C# coding... A bit verbose compared to other languages...

Comment: 1. You can declare variables in the first clause of the `for` loop. 2. `int.Parse` is shorter than `Convert.ToInt32`. 3. `long` is shorter than `double` and more accurate for this task. 4. `t` is unnecessary: you can count `n` down to `0` instead. 5. Technically I think you need to break two loops after printing, in case there's a triple coincidence.

Comment: Untested: `static void Main(){for(long a,b,c=3,n=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());n>0;c++)for(a=2;a<c;a++)for(b=a;b<c;b++)if(a*a*a+b*b*b==c*c*c+1)Console.WriteLine(c*c*(a=c)+n/n--);}`

Comment: You can also compile to an `Action` which will save the bytes used in the method signature i.e. `()=>{/*code here*/};`

Comment: You would also need to fully qualify names or add `using System;` into the byte count

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thanks for the great tips! I'm totally new to C#

Comment: @TheLethalCoder thanks for your advices, unfortunately adding `using System;` canceled all the previous code golfing :(

Comment: You can compile to an `Action<int>` which removes the method signature stuff, means you do not need to have to use `Console.ReadLine` to take input, so you can then fully qualify `Console.WriteLine` to `System.Console.WriteLine` saving the `using` statement from the byte count:

Comment: `n=>{for(long a,b,d,c=3;n>0;c++)for(a=2;a<c;a++)for(b=a;b<c;b++)if(a*a*a+b*b*b==c*c*c+1)System.Console.WriteLin‌e(c*c*(a=c)+n/n--);};`  for 132 bytes I believe

Comment: You also declare the long value `d` but never use it so you can remove that from the byte count too

Comment: @TheLethalCoder I forgot to remove `d` variable! (always rushing...) Thanks. About your code `n=>{for(long...` is there no input parameter? I'm not sure I understand it :P

Comment: @Mario See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JkmJo3) for an example. But note you only need to include the `n=>{/*code here*/};` part and can ignore the `Action...` for the byte count

Comment: @TheLethalCoder, shame you can't use `yield return` in a lambda.

Comment: @PeterTaylor yeah annoyed me a few times before, but the challenge asks to print the output so not sure if that is acceptable anyway

Comment: @TheLethalCoder thanks a lot for your great golfing! I consider that your answer because I had no idea, thanks for teaching me new things! Only one thing (that I don't understand now why) your golfed solution is about 3,5 times slower than my original code, I noticed a lot of difference in runtime, so wanted to measure it and added in the post the execution times.

Comment: @Mario No worries, and I don't know why I never actually tested the code just gave you some tips to help take off some bytes

Answer (score 0):

## GameMaker Language, 119 bytes

Why is `show_message()` so long :(

```
x=2y=3z=4w=argument0 while n>0{if x*x*x+y*y*y-z*z*z=1&x<y&y<z{show_message(z*z*z+1)n--}x++if y<x{x=2y++}if z<y{y=3z++}}
```

x,y,z=2,3,4
n=input()
while n:
 if y**3+x**3-z3==1and x3+1;n-=1
 x+=1
 if y

Answer (score 0):

## Axiom, 246 bytes

```
h(x:PI):List INT==(r:List INT:=[];i:=0;a:=1;repeat(a:=a+1;b:=1;t:=a^3;repeat(b:=b+1;b>=a=>break;q:=t+b^3;l:=gcd(q-1,223092870);l~=1 and(q-1)rem(l^3)~=0=>0;c:=round((q-1)^(1./3))::INT;if c^3=q-1 then(r:=cons(q,r);i:=i+1;i>=x=>return reverse(r)))))
```

ungof and result

```
-- hh returns x in 1.. numbers in a INT list [y_1,...y_x] such that 
-- for every y_k exist a,b,c in N with y_k=a^3+b^3=c^3+1 
hh(x:PI):List INT==
   r:List INT:=[]
   i:=0;a:=1
   repeat
      a:=a+1
      b:=1
      t:=a^3
      repeat
          b:=b+1
          b>=a=>break
          q:=t+b^3
          l:=gcd(q-1,223092870);l~=1 and (q-1)rem(l^3)~=0 =>0 -- if l|(q-1)=> l^3|(q-1)
          c:=round((q-1.)^(1./3.))::INT
          if c^3=q-1 then(r:=cons(q,r);i:=i+1;output[i,a,b,c];i>=x=>return reverse(r))

(3) -> h 12
   (3)
   [1729, 1092728, 3375001, 15438250, 121287376, 401947273, 3680797185,
    6352182209, 7856862273, 12422690497, 73244501505, 145697644729]
                                                       Type: List Integer
```